# Error while trying to convert the Array to Int

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

So i've taken my bundle version and save it in an array but it s of type String. I ve tried and .map it to be Int but i receive `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type''((String.Element))`

```
let versionName = String(describing: Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]!)  // 1.9.1

let versionNumeral = Array(versionName.westernArabicNumeralsOnly)   // ["1","9","1"]

 let convertedToInt = versionNumeral.map {Int($0)} // so i want it here to be [1, 9, 1] so  I can add them between them.

for element in convertedToInt {
    total += element
}
```

.westernArabicNumeralsOnly is a string extension  that removes my dots from version and only let the numbers

```
extension String {
    var westernArabicNumeralsOnly: String {
        let pattern = UnicodeScalar("0")..."9"
        return String(unicodeScalars
            .flatMap { pattern ~= $0 ? Character($0) : nil })
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we help you without knowing what  `westernArabicNumeralsOnly` returns?

Comment: If you do `let versionNumeral = ["1","9","1"]`, you code works. So the next question is: `westernArabicNumeralsOnly` being? That seems to be the issue.

Comment: i've edited my question. That extension removes the dots and returs "191"

Comment: Is there any specific reason to write String extension, since you can use versionName.components(separatedBy: ".")  , with which now total can be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct conversion between Characters and Ints. If you are wanting to extract the version numbers from the string the following might be a better way to do it. It would also allow for version numbers greater than 9

```
let versionName = String(describing: Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]!)  // 1.9.1
let versionComponents = versionName.components(separatedBy: ".")
let convertedToInt = versionComponents.map {Int($0)}
```

This version would output an array of Int?. If you want an array of Int then you could use

```
let convertedToInt = versionComponents.map {Int($0)!}
```

but you'd have to be sure you aren't sent a string with non-numerical characters in it.

Comment: Or use `.flatMap {Int($0)}` to ignore non-integers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this:

```
let versionString = (Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String) ?? ""
let versionInts = versionString.components(separatedBy: ".").map { Int($0) ?? 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Fetch number easily without westernArabicNumeralsOnly function

```
    let versionName = String(describing: Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]!)  // 1.9.1
    let versionNumeral = Array(versionName.components(separatedBy: "."))   // ["1","9","1"]
    let convertedToInt = versionNumeral.map{Int($0)} // [1,9,1]
    var total = 0
    for element in convertedToInt {
        total = total + element!
    }
    print(total) // 11
```